# How to Fix Blurry Thumbnail Images in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I faced blurry image issue in WordPress. You can see it on the screenshot:
[image]

In the console, the image code is generated in this way:

[image]

You see the red arrow in the picture, so if I change this value to 800 in the console, then everything looks good. Here is an example:

[image]

But I don’t know how to change this value through the code or admin panel. Tell me who is guided in this matter.

Comment: Is this something you add via the post editor or is it the featured image? If it's the editor, what size image are you inserting?

Comment: @TomWoodward This is the featured image.

Comment: Its displaying the 200px version of the image. You could possibly change the thumbnail or other sizes in your media settings to a larger value (400 x 400, or whatever you choose) and that would produce a larger file within that range (400 x 92 and not shrink it to 200 x 50*). If the odd shaped images are being cropped to fit the requirements of your media settings it might be showing a 200px image where a 400px image should ve making it look blurry?

Just a thought without knowing more of your issue.

Comment: @Aliqua Yes, I I tried resizing thumbnails in multimedia settings. There was 150px to 150px . I changed to 400px to 400px But nothing has changed( It’s generally strange that WordPress predetermines such small images.

Comment: You'll need to regenerate the thumbnail sizes to get that change in media sizes to apply. If you've only got a few images, just reupload them and set the thumbnail to the new image. If you have many, there are plugins to regenerate all thumbnail sizes.

Comment: I love the way you added images and arrows. Helped me to at least find a clue to my problem too. Changing that "200px" value in my own image html fixed the image blurry as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am grateful to all who tried to help me. But unfortunately no one option I did not load. Nevertheless, I found a solution to the problem. There is an attribute sizes  in the image code.

```
sizes="(max-width: 200px) 100vw, 200px";
```

I just deleted it with jQuery.

```
$('.list-count > img').removeAttr("sizes");
```

And the blur is gone. Perhaps there is a better solution to this issue, but in my case it worked just the way it should. And here is an example that the images are not blurry now:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for that solution!
it made an enormous impact on my site

Comment: Good ol nuke it with JavaScript solution. Hats off to you sir.

Answer (score 0):

Another simple way to fix this is to inspect the image and find its URL to upload your own version. My images were 150x150px, and I made my own version in Photoshop and uploaded it to the same location in WordPress uploads with FTP. This made a 100% improvement in the image quality. The thumbnails WordPress generates are very poor quality.